# iPhone - UIButton background image is cut off sometimes

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am using a custom image as the background image for my buttons. I have noticed that the edges of the buttons are cut off sometimes. My buttons vary in size but the behavior doesn't seem to be dependent on the button size. I am creating the buttons programatically. The image I am using is pretty large to cover the entire background.

Can someone please let me know what could be the issue?

**More info**

Setting the content mode to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill still cuts of the images. Also tried resizing the image but doesn't make a difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this by creating a 3x3 px image with the background color as the button's color and a 1 px border surrounding the image. Then used the UIImage method stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight: to create an image with the desired border size of 1 px.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the button's dimensions to fit exactly the image?

Is the image just cropped or also blurry (cause it's being resized)? Have you toyed around with `UIView`'s `contentMode` property for the button?

If you did, did you try increasing/decreasing the width or height by a pixel? I sometimes had blurry buttons even though its dimensions were exactly the image's. Adding or removing an extra pixel sometimes helped.

Comment: Not setting the contentMode, the button is smaller than the image - that is why am setting the image as the button's backgroundImage and not image so it occupies the entire area of the button. Will try resizing the image.